# Flutter Text Field: hold down delete only deletes on character

Tags: android, flutter

**The problem:**
When holding down the delete button, only one character gets deleted. That is, you cannot hold down to continuously delete more characters. This happens on my newer Flutter app, using Flutter 2.0.6. With an identical setup, this doesn't happen on older versions (tested on: Flutter 1.20.1).

**Minimal Code to reproduce:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ExperimentApp());
}

class ExperimentApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ExperimentHome(myData: MyData()),
    );
  }
}

class ExperimentHome extends StatefulWidget {
  final MyData myData;
  ExperimentHome({required this.myData});  // use @required for older ver.
  @override
  _ExperimentHomeState createState() => _ExperimentHomeState();
}

class _ExperimentHomeState extends State<ExperimentHome> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      widget.myData.field = _controller.text;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          autofocus: true,
          controller: _controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Field: ',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyData {
  String field;
  MyData({this.field = ''});
}
```

**Other Information:**

- When typing in more words, nothing gets logged but once delete button is pressed the following gets logged (this doesn't get logged on the older version):

```
[+19307 ms] D/InputMethodManager(14233): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@f73d46f[MainActivity]
[        ] D/InputMethodManager(14233): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
[        ] V/InputMethodManager(14233): Starting input: tba=[REDACTED application id] ic=io.flutter.plugin.editing.InputConnectionAdaptor@8a40558 mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
[        ] D/InputMethodManager(14233): startInputInner - Id : 0
[        ] I/InputMethodManager(14233): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
[   +8 ms] D/InputTransport(14233): Input channel constructed: fd=102
[        ] D/InputTransport(14233): Input channel destroyed: fd=100
[   +4 ms] D/InputMethodManager(14233): SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 14233 view : [REDACTED application id]
[        ] D/InputMethodManager(14233): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@f73d46f[MainActivity]
[        ] D/InputMethodManager(14233): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
[   +2 ms] D/InputMethodManager(14233): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@f73d46f[MainActivity]
[        ] D/InputMethodManager(14233): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
[        ] V/InputMethodManager(14233): Starting input: tba=[REDACTED application id] ic=io.flutter.plugin.editing.InputConnectionAdaptor@c093796 mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
[        ] D/InputMethodManager(14233): startInputInner - Id : 0
[        ] I/InputMethodManager(14233): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
[   +2 ms] D/InputTransport(14233): Input channel constructed: fd=100
[        ] D/InputTransport(14233): Input channel destroyed: fd=102
[   +5 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14233): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

- no exceptions or errors were thrown.

Comment: I have seen this happen too. But only on some phones I guess. I have seen this case on my Samsung Galaxy S7, whereas then when I tried the same on a OnePlus, it was working fine.

Comment: Are you by any chance referring to this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82427#issue-890817181? Have you found a workaround or is there nothing we can do at the moment?

Comment: No, that looks like a different issue. The issue I am referring to is same as you described -_"When holding down the delete button, only one character gets deleted. That is, you cannot hold down to continuously delete more characters."_. I don't know of a workaround at the moment and I'm also not sure if this is limited to some phones only. But it worked fine on a OnePlus when I checked. On which phone do you see this issue? Or are you seeing this on an emulator?

Comment: @JigarPatel I see, thanks for the information. Where would I likely find a future update/fix for this?